# From cooccurrence matrix to edges list data separation

Tags: python, list

i have a huge cooccurence matrix with indexes as skill_id and column names as skill_id, and the matrix is filled with the co-occurence of the same. please find the sample below
[image: cooccurrence matrix data]

I want the data in a 3 column dataframe: skillid1    skillid2    count
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: Please reformat your question such that your situation is easily reproducible. No screenshots should be attached, but rather a code snippet to get to your DataFrame, or a minimal exemple of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your cooccurrence matrix is called `df` and looks like that :

```
      4044 4092 4651 6168 6229 6284 6295
4044    0    0    0    1    1   0    0
4092    0    0    1    0    0   0    0
4651    0    1    0    0    0   0    0
6168    1    0    0    0    1   0    0
6229    1    0    0    1    0   0    0
6284    0    0    0    0    0   0    1
6295    0    0    0    0    0   1    0
```

I'd suggest the following :

```
import itertools

# get all possible pairs of (skillid1, skillid2)
edges = list(itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2))  

# find associated weights in the original df
edges_with_weights = [(node1, node2, df.loc[node1][node2]) for (node1, node2) in edges]

# put it all in a new dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame(vertices_with_weights, columns=["skillid1", "skillid2", "count"])
```

Such that now you have your desired `new_df`:

```
    skillid1    skillid2    count
0   4044          4092        0
1   4044          4651        0
2   4044          6168        1
3   4044          6229        1
4   4044          6284        0
5   4044          6295        0
6   4092          4651        1
7   4092          6168        0
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
weights = []`
for skill_id in skills.skill_id:
if str(skill_id) in count_model.vocabulary_.keys():
    i = count_model.vocabulary_[str(skill_id)]
    j = count_model.vocabulary_[str(skill_id)]
    if (skills_occurrences[i][j] > 0) and () :
        weights.append([skill_id, skill_id, skills_occurrences[i][j]])
for combination in combinations(skills.skill_id, 2):
if str(combination[0]) in count_model.vocabulary_.keys() and str(combination[1]) in count_model.vocabulary_.keys():
    i = count_model.vocabulary_[str(combination[0])]
    j = count_model.vocabulary_[str(combination[1])]
    if skills_occurrences[i][j] > 0:
        weights.append([str(combination[0]), str(combination[1]), skills_occurrences[i][j]])
```

Had one more data set to process, after that just nested looped both skillids and compared them and kept on appending the value and the value in the indices.